# not response for database

Tags: php, database

This is the code for database connection in `php`:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root"); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("fimos", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL

    $gender = $_POST["gender"]; //declare gender 
    $race = $_POST["race"];
    $ic = $_POST["icno"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $old_ic = $_POST["oldic"];
    $add1 = $_POST["add1"];
    $add2 = $_POST["add2"];
    $add3 = $_POST["add3"];
    $postcode = $_POST["postco"];
    $town = $_POST["tow"];
    $state = $_POST["state"];
    $home_con = $_POST["homep"];
    $fax_contact = $_POST["fax"];
    $hp_con1 = $_POST["mobi1"];
    $hp_con2 = $_POST["mobi2"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    if($ic !=''||$email !=''){
        //Insert Query of SQL
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_info(cust_gender, cust_race,  cust_ic, 
            cust_name, cust_old_ic, cust_add1, cust_add2, cust_add3, cust_postcode,  
            cust_town, cust_state, cust_home_con, cust_fax_contact, cust_hp_contact1,  
            cust_hp_contact2, cust_email) 
            VALUES ('$gender', '$race', '$ic' , '$name', '$old_ic', '$add1', '$add2', 
            '$add3', '$postcode', '$town', '$state',  '$home_con', '$fax_contact', 
            '$hp_con1', '$hp_con2', '$email')");
        echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
    }
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
```

Hi guys, I want to ask about the database connection, is it my code wrong somewhere?
Because I cant found any error in the code.

- I click button register should come over this page to store the data.
- when I come to this page display all blank.
- I try to change the database name also no response.

I hope you guys can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //empty the third parameter. If you have password then insert that in your third parameter
```

Comment: ya I have password if not will me pass this 
https://i.gyazo.com/1a7251f032a8a851c8972b37fe5868e8.png

Comment: Is your password root?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code inside your if condition so that it will return error from your sql query.

```
if (!$query) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Try to use the PDO extension instead of mysql & mysqli function. The mysql_* functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) process. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) there are lots of benefits of using PDO over mysqli.

Add the above code

```
if($ic !=''||$email !=''){
     $query = mysql_query("your query");
     if (!$query) {
         die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
     } else {
         echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
     }
}
```

Comment: Where i want to add this code? Can u show me? Thanks